# Json Serialize ignore properties when not assigning value but property should be present when assign null

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a Class defined as Car, I want to serialize as JSON as ignore the properties when you don't assign anything to property but the property should present in JSON if I assign as null.

Example:

```
 public class Car
    {
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

1. Case 1

if I assign the value as below

```
            Car car = new Car();
            car.CarId = 1;
            car.Color = "Black";
            car.Brand = "Hundai";
            car.Model = null;
```

Expected JSON would come as

```
{
  "CarId": 1,
  "Brand": "Hundai",
  "Model": null,
  "Color": "Black"
}
```

2. Case 2

if I assign the value as below(***`car.Model` is not assigned***)

```
            Car car = new Car();
            car.CarId = 1;
            car.Color = "Black";
            car.Brand = "Hundai";
```

Expected JSON would be

```
{
  "CarId": 1,
  "Brand": "Hundai",
  "Color": "Black"
}
```

I have used the Newtonsoft Json library as below but not able to get the expected output

```
string jsonIgnoreNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
            });
```

Comment: You can use default value `""` for this property. Not sure which value to use for [DefaultValueHandlding](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) to skip it. Setting value to `null` will be non-default and it will be serialized.

Comment: have you tired with `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]` on property

Comment: yes @viveknuna , I have tried as an attribute as well. but no luck.

Comment: As @Sinatr said, null value means the value is not assigned, so if you assign the property to null value or leave it as default it will be handled the same by serializing process.

Comment: yes, @AbdulrazzaqAlzayed - I agree with u both, but my requirement is to show the property if u assign(either null or some value), and don't show if it is not assigned.

Comment: Can you explain why you want the JSON result to be like this?, may be we can help you with better solution.

Comment: Assigning value to null is the same as not assigning at all.

Comment: @AbdulrazzaqAlzayed - Here is my requirement...I need to integrate to some third party WebAPI, which they have one endpoint for Create and Edit with the same JSON payload, So they mentioned in edit transaction if i pass the property as null, they will override the existing value to null internally in their database, so they suggested not to pass the property in JSON if you want to remain the existing value in the database, only pass the property with null if u want to override the value in their database

Comment: @suryateja I got your point, may be in this case you can pass string value "null" instead of null keyword and agreed with the third party team when they see only this string to override the existing value. and of course you still have to use `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;` but with the new "null" string the serializing process will handle it different.

Comment: @suryateja , I found a better solution for you, I will put it in as answer below with better details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To be more generic you have to create your own ContractResolver class**

**Step 1:** Car class should be as following:

```
public class Car {
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; } = "null"; // Default value
    public string Model { get; set; } = "null"; // Default value
    public string Color { get; set; } = "null"; // Default value
}
```

**Step 2:** You will need to create the following class:

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver {
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (!property.PropertyName.Equals("CarId")) {
            property.ShouldSerialize =
                instance => {
                    var car = (Car)instance;
                    var value = car.GetType().GetProperty(property.PropertyName).GetValue(car, null);
                    return value == null || !value.ToString().Equals("null");
                };
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** create car object:

```
var car = new Car {
    CarId = 1,
    Brand = "Hundai",
    Model = null
};
```

**Step 4:** Serialize the object - *Notice how we create ContractResolver here* :

```
var SerializedCar = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car, 
   Formatting.Indented, 
   new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver()
});
```

**Step 5:** Print the output:

```
Console.WriteLine(SerializedCar);
```

**Finally:** The result:

```
   {
       "CarId": 1,
       "Brand": "Hundai",
       "Model": null
   }
```

Comment: That's Awesome..Thank you so much @Abdulrazzaq for helping..

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Modify the Car class to be as following:

```
public class Car {
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; } = "null"; // Default value
    public string Model { get; set; } = "null"; // Default value
    public string Color { get; set; } = "null"; // Default value

    // Serialize only when the default value changed
    public bool ShouldSerializeBrand() {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Brand) || !Brand.Equals("null");
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeModel() {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model) || !Model.Equals("null");
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeColor() {
        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Color) || !Color.Equals("null");
    }

}
```

**Step 2:** Now when you create the car object as following:

```
 var car = new Car {
     CarId = 1,
     Brand = "Hundai",
     Model = null
 };
```

**Step 3:** Serialize the object as following:

```
var SerializedCar = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car, Formatting.Indented);
```

**Step 4:** write the output to console

```
Console.WriteLine(SerializedCar);
```

**Finally:** The result exactly as you expected:

```
{
  "CarId": 1,
  "Brand": "Hundai",
  "Model": null
}
```

I tested it with different cases, it working fine.

Comment: That's cool..But, Is there any way that the ShouldSeralize() Method can make it generic for all the properties? , Because if there are more than 100s of properties it will be difficult.

Comment: @suryateja, Yes of course there is a way, I will Modify my answer to show you how to do it

Comment: Or better I will add another answer to avoiding confusing you and the readers.